# Bootstrap 4 - two colums not working on mobile

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a row of buttons which look fine on medium and large screens.

I'm using Bootstrap 4 and I want those buttons to move into two columns on mobile devices.

I've added xs and sm col 6 so not sure where the problem is:

```
<div class = "container-fluid">
    <div class = "col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
        <button> Biz </button>
        <button> Charity </button>
        <button> Health </button>
        <button> Media </button>
        <button> Politics </button>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
        <button> Tech </button>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you want 2 columns for  `xs` and `sm`, where is the other `div` containing `col-xs-6 col-sm-6`? You showed us the `div` that will occupy the first 6 column grids, the `div` occupying the last 6 column grids is missing. But reading on the question, it seems that you want to split the 6 buttons inside that `div` into two columns, correct?

Comment: Oops, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `xs` in bs4, also you should have a `row` wrapper div for `col-*`

Use this (here `col-lg-12` is redundant as `col-md-12` styles will be applied to all higher viewports, unless you need different layout for large and extra large viewports)

```
<div class="row">
    <div class = "col-6 col-md-12 col-lg-12">Col 1</div>
    <div class = "col-6 col-md-12 col-lg-12">Col 2</div>
</div>
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6 col-md-12">
      <button> Biz </button>
      <button> Charity </button>
      <button> Health </button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 col-md-12">
      <button> Media </button>
      <button> Politics </button>
      <button> Tech </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```